# How to access shared hosting database with Java desktop application

Tags: java, database, synchronization, desktop, shared-hosting

I was looking for a solution for one of my questions. I have developed a Java desktop application. I have a database in a shared php hosting server. Is there any possible way to connect the shared hosting database with my Java desktop application. And how can I perform timed database synchronization with the shared database server

Thanks in advance

Mujahid

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the shared hosting provider allows SSH file transfers, check to see if you can create a tunnel to the database server, and configure your desktop application to use that tunnel to connect.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tassos, I could do it with database syncronization through the SQLYog Software and your idea helped me to come up to a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, for security reasons %99,99 of shared hosting servers would not allow that.

However you can programm a gateway php string that interacts with db on the server side. Then you can connect to this php script from your java app:

`your java app` <-> `php script` <-> `db`

Comment: hi LAS_VEGAS, if you have any code samples, pls share it with me, would be a great help, thanks